# how i can store the video and audio files in firebase storage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, web-applications, firebase-storage

i am creating an mediaRecorder webapp using javascript in visual studio code. and i want to get my audio and video files get directly stores in firebase storage. when i click on stop recording its generate a download link but in simultenously i want that when i press on stop button the file directly stores in firebase storage.?

## index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>MediaRecorder</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="keywords" content="WebRTC getUserMedia MediaRecorder API">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" 
    integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <style>
      button{
        margin: 20px 50px;
        font-style: italic;
      }
      li{
        margin: 50px;
      }
      body{
        width: 90%;
        max-width: 960px;
        margin: 0px auto;
      }
      #btns{
        display: none;
        color: rgb(252, 114, 9);

      }
      body {
      color: rgb(252, 114, 9);
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 1.8;
}

      h1 {
      color: rgb(6, 243, 6);
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 5.0;
      font-size: 40px;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      background: linear-gradient(to right, #f32170,
      #ffc908, #cf23cf, #eedd44);
      -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
      -webkit-background-clip: text;
        }      
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> MediaRecorder Using API</h1>
    <p style="font-size: 50px"><b>Welcome to MY App.</b></p>
    <div id='gUMArea'>
      <div>
      Record:
        <input type="radio" name="media" value="video" checked id='mediaVideo'>Video
        <input type="radio" name="media" value="audio">audio
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-default"  id='gUMbtn'><b>Request Stream</b></button>
    </div>
    <div id='btns'>
      <button  class="btn btn-default" id='start'>Start</button>
      <button  class="btn btn-default" id='stop'>Stop</button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul  class="list-styled" id='ul'></ul>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" 
    integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>


    <script type="module">
      // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
      import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-app.js";
      import { getAnalytics } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-analytics.js";
      import { getStorage, ref} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.15.0/firebase-storage.js";
      // TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
      // https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries
    
      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
      // For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
      const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "AIzaSyCWOdeArFIfm_VrhaP_Boe0Ly7ID51aodM",
        authDomain: "mediarecorder-dda3b.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://mediarecorder-dda3b-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
        projectId: "mediarecorder-dda3b",
        storageBucket: "gs://mediarecorder-dda3b.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "152268264978",
        appId: "1:152268264978:web:b6233300016d25e4f12acb",
        measurementId: "G-E69QHKH7LF"
      };
    
      // Initialize Firebase
      const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
      const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
      const storage = getStorage();
      const storageRef = ref(storage, );
      const mediaRef = ref(storageRef, 'medias');
      const fileName = '1.ogg';
      const mediasRef = ref(mediaRef, fileName);
      const path = mediaRef.fullPath;


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

## script.js

```
'use strict'
let log = console.log.bind(console),
  id = val => document.getElementById(val),
  ul = id('ul'),
  gUMbtn = id('gUMbtn'),
  start = id('start'),
  stop = id('stop'),
  stream,
  recorder,
  counter=1,
  chunks,
  media;


gUMbtn.onclick = e => {
  let mv = id('mediaVideo'),
      mediaOptions = {
        video: {
          tag: 'video',
          type: 'video/webm',
          ext: '.mp4',
          gUM: {video: true, audio: true}
        },
        audio: {
          tag: 'audio',
          type: 'audio/ogg',
          ext: '.ogg',
          gUM: {audio: true}
        }
      };
  media = mv.checked ? mediaOptions.video : mediaOptions.audio;
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(media.gUM).then(_stream => {
    stream = _stream;
    id('gUMArea').style.display = 'none';
    id('btns').style.display = 'inherit';
    start.removeAttribute('disabled');
    recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
    recorder.ondataavailable = e => {
      chunks.push(e.data);
      if(recorder.state == 'inactive')  makeLink();
    };
    log('got media successfully');
  }).catch(log);
}

start.onclick = e => {
  start.disabled = true;
  stop.removeAttribute('disabled');
  chunks=[];
  recorder.start();
}


stop.onclick = e => {
  stop.disabled = true;
  recorder.stop();
  start.removeAttribute('disabled');
}



function makeLink(){
    let blob = new Blob(chunks, {type: media.type })
  ,  url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  ,  li = document.createElement('li')
  ,  mt = document.createElement(media.tag)
  ,  hf = document.createElement('a')
;
  mt.controls = true;
  mt.src = url;
  hf.href = url;
  hf.download = `${counter++}${media.ext}`;
  hf.innerHTML = `download ${hf.download}`;"<span style='color: red;'>**Message</span>";
  li.appendChild(mt);
  li.appendChild(hf);
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's great to describe your expected result but we need some further information about your code. Where is it failing? Did you do some basic troubleshooting by adding a breakpoint and stepping through the code line by line, inspecting the vars and code execution until you spot something unexpected? If so, what was the result of that. Please update the question with your troubleshooting and indicate what line is not working as expected.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).